# (Wordpress) How can i get the full content of a post with the html tags - unstripped

Tags: php, html, wordpress, tags, qtranslate

I'm using WordPress for my site with the qtranslate plugin and i'm trying to display language flags in each post.

Qtranslate inserts html tags to the content and title like
"!--:en-->" 
for each language that i used in each post

So i need a conditional that checks which of these html tags are included in the content so i can print the specific flags

something like this:

```
function language_pick(){
    $qt_dir = "http://localhost/MY-SITE/wp-content/plugins/qtranslate-xp/flags/";
    $cr_url = "http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    $en_url = esc_html($cr_url."&lang=en");
    $fr_url = esc_html($cr_url."&lang=fr");
    $it_url = esc_html($cr_url."&lang=it");
    $es_url = esc_html($cr_url."&lang=es");

    $query = get_post(get_the_ID()); 
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $query->post_content);

    if(get_permalink() != $cr_url) { echo '<a style="margin-left:15px;" href="'.$cr_url.'" /><img src="'.$qt_dir.'gr.png"></a>'; }
    if (strpos($content, '<!--:en-->') === true) {
         if(get_permalink() != $en_url) { echo '<a style="margin-left:15px;" href="'.$en_url.'" /><img src="'.$qt_dir.'gb.png"></a>'; } }
    if(strpos($content,'<!--:fr-->') === true) {
        if(get_permalink() != $fr_url) { echo '<a style="margin-left:15px;" href="'.$fr_url.'" /><img src="'.$qt_dir.'fr.png"></a>'; } }
    if(strpos($content,'<!--:it-->') === true) {
        if(get_permalink() != $it_url) { echo '<a style="margin-left:15px;" href="'.$it_url.'" /><img src="'.$qt_dir.'it.png"></a>'; } }
    if(strpos($content,'<!--:es-->') === true) {
        if(get_permalink() != $es_url) { echo '<a style="margin-left:15px;" href="'.$es_url.'" /><img src="'.$qt_dir.'es.png"></a>'; } }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Very simply add `<?= apply_filters('the_content', $content); ?>`

There are loads of references to this on Google.

**EDIT**
So in this case:

```
$query = get_post(get_the_ID()); 
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $query->post_content);

echo $content;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Where exactly should i put this in my code? the code above is in a function that i call in content-single.php, right after the_title()

Comment: and to be a little more specific: 
    $query = get_post(get_the_ID());
    $content = $query->post_content;
When i "echo" this (for check only), it's already stripped of html.

Comment: Unfortunately it echos the content only in the default language so the conditional can't find html tags for other languages...
Is there another way to grab the content from the database with the html tags as text?

Comment: This is because you are simply copying and pasting what I have done. You don't have to echo it! Use $content however you wish! It will have whatever is (inc. html tags) in $query->post_content

Comment: It works!
instead of: if(strpos($title,'<!--:en-->') == true), 
This seems to do the trick: if(strpos($title,':en') == true)

Answer (score 1):

This simply helped in single post template to render HTML tags as you see in the editor/

```
$content = apply_filters('the_content', get_the_content());
echo $content ;
```