# WordPress: Check how many elements are in a post

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there any way to check how many elements like headlines (h2,h3,...), paragraphs and links are in a WordPress post?

At the moment I'm using this code:

```
<?php
    $content = get_the_content();

    $count_h2s = explode('<h2>', $content);
    $h2 = 0;

    foreach ($count_h2s as $count_h2) {
            $h2++;
    }
    echo $h2;
?>
```

It seems to work for the headlines. But if I'm using it to count `<p>`-tags I only get a count of 1. Even if there are more. I could imagine this is because these tags are not in the editor but headlines are?!

And maybe there is a more elegant way to count the elements than my code ;)

Comment: Maybe you can find the open tags and count the matches, `preg_match_all('/\<\w+\>/', $content, $matches); echo count($matches);`

Comment: do I have to edit the code? It shows a result of 1. But what does it count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop is not necessary, use PHP function [substr_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php)

```
$query = get_post(get_the_ID());    
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $query->post_content);
$p_count = substr_count($content, '<p>');
echo $p_count ;

// Be aware, if there is a more-tag inside the post, this `<p>`-tag wouldn't count!
```

Should be easy to use it for other tags, such as ...

Comment: thanks, but no I get 0 results for `<p>`. Maybe because `<p>` is not set in the editor? But it's in the HTML of the post. It works for the headlines.

Comment: Check the source you are scanning to see if there is any `<p>`?

Comment: I've checked the source, there are more than 10  `<p>` tags

Comment: Then it is quite strange. If you just assign the `$content` with a string including lot of `<p>` to see what you get. It works well in my test.

Comment: I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32024022/1788961 We need to get the content with all tags like this: `$content = apply_filters('the_content', $query->post_content);`

Comment: That's right, the output from `get_the_content();` is different.

Comment: strange, the count for `<p>` is always 1 short?! instead of 10 it counts only 9. OK, has to do with the more tag inside the '<p>`. If there is one, it doesn't count

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're getting thrown off by the filter wordpress uses to automatically convert line breaks into `<p>` tags. The line breaks aren't in your editor because they are being added through the filter after the fact.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop

So, while you're seeing the `<p>` tags in the HTML source of your page, you want to search your `get_the_content()` for line breaks, instead, as these are what's being converted to `<p>` tags.

Comment: Thanks, I found a solution. I need to get the content like this: `$content = apply_filters('the_content', $query->post_content);`